# Identify calling module in requirejs

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

I want to make a sort of loader class. Consider:

config.js

```
define(function() {
     return {
       appViews : [
            'baseViews',
            'fullDocViews', 
            'docCreateViews',
            'accountViews',
            'fullDocViews',
            'notifyViews'
        ]
    }
}
```

loader.js

```
define(['config', 'underscore'], function (Config, _) {
    var Loader = {};

    _.each(Config.appViews, function (view) {
        var include = 'views/'+view;
        Loader[view] = require([include], function (Include) {
            return Include;
        });
    });
    return Loader;
});
```

fullDocViews.js

```
define(['loader'], function (Loader) {
    var moduleView = Loader.baseViews.BaseView.extend({
        // Loving life here...
    })
});
```

This, however, creates a circular dependency, since calling the loader calls fullDocsView module. Is there any way that, in loader.js, I can exclude the calling module from the resulting hash of views?

So what I'm looking for is this:

```
define(['config', 'underscore'], function (Config, _) {
    var Loader = {};

    _.each(Config.appViews, function (view) {
        if (view !== callingView) {
            var include = 'views/'+view;
            Loader[view] = require([include], function (Include) {
                return Include;
            });
        }
    });
    return Loader;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem with your code but it is not the circular dependency. This won't work:

```
Loader[view] = require([include], function (Include) {
    return Include;
});
```

Because:

1. The return value of a `require` call which takes an array of dependencies is not a module. (It is a function named `localRequire`, which is one of the incarnations of the `require` function.)
2. The return value of the callback used for a `require` call is swallowed by RequireJS.

Why is it this way, because a call to require like this is asynchronous. The module is going to be available at some indeterminate time in the future.

There is a `require` call which returns a module value: `require("module")`. You pass a single module name rather than an array. This kind of call either returns a module if it is *already* loaded, or fails right away.

As for the circular dependency, I do not believe RequireJS exposes the name of what module caused another module to be loaded. The way it [handles circular dependencies](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#circular) is that if A requires B which requires A, then B must be ready to accept that when it is instantiated, the value it gets for A is going to be `undefined`. It can then require A again later, and get a real value.

Comment: Thanks for the great response. Node has module.parent which seems to do what I'm looking for in require.js